# Adding a border to a table in a rich text field not showing up when form is previewed

Tags: lotus-notes, richtext

Could you please help me? I'm trying to add a border to a table in a rich text field. I tried the following:

1. In the table properties, I tried setting the border to 2 in all sides and saved the document.
2. In the richtext field property - HTML tags, I tried placing the "<" table border=2 ">" under Style. (I used "" to the <> because it's reading as basic html)

All these did not work. The border is showing normally in the form, but once previewed it's not showing anymore. Please see photos.

[Saved form where the border of the table is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF70w.png)

[Previewed form where the border of the table is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFAp.png)

Comment: Is that a preview in the Notes client, or a preview in the browser?

Comment: Hi. Rich text preview in Notes client @RichardSchwartz

Comment: I guess I'm still a little bit confused. You say it's a table in a rich text field, and you say you set the properties and saved the document. But then you talk about previewing the form. That sounds like you are using the "Preview in Notes" feature of Domino Designer, but you can't put a table inside a rich text field in Domino Designer - it would be directly on the form instead.